# How to stop dog from peeing here/prevent stains

Tags: cleaning, home, stain, house-cleaning

Sharing photos here.
One photo original
One photo showing where the dog pees on the ledge at entrance of the shower.

Issue: dog goes into shower to pee on pee pad, then also pees on the ledge causing spill over and wrecked by urine stains on granite.

Tried and failed previously:

- added objects, items to reduce surface area on ledge but dog will pee outside on bath mat or tiles.

Question:

Can anyone think of some brilliant and simple hack for this?
To prevent dog from peeing and urine saturating the granite.

Is there a type of cover that is safe?
Or some type of coverage that prevents dog to pee there?

If I cover the ledge with a rubber mat, dog may refuse to cross into shower to pee on mat.

Note: dog is very small, and generally in door dog. Very self sufficient and access washroom when required.

Thank you for your time in  brainstorming.

[image]

Comment: This may be better asked on Pets.se, where there are many similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

If the dog wants to pee on the step into the shower, I guess it is better to protect the step than to try to prevent it. So

- Place another pee pad over the step (perhaps diagonally).
- Perhaps spread a plastic bin liner over the step first, to protect it.

Presumably this pee facility is what you provide when you are out. The better solution is to walk the dog more frequently. If you can't do that, perhaps consider whether the dog would be happier rehomed: they are social creatures and it is unkind to leave them alone for long periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

I mean... Move the pee pad further to the right. The dog is obviously putting its front paws on the pad and then going for it. Thinking... well Im on this thing let her rip.

Moving the pad to the right as shown in the picture will prevent the front paws from being able to reach the pad before the dog is fully in the shower. That way even if it misses the pad... Its in the shower. :)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's a male dog? They have an instinct to pee as high as possible (think about peeing against a tree trunk). Since the step is higher than the pad, it's prime target.

First you should clean the step with a special enzymatic cleaner. That breaks down the urine smell on a chemical level. I'm honestly not sure how compatible it is with granite, you'll need to test it for yourself. But that should "unmark" the step as a valid target for pee.

Then think about adding an artificial tree trunk to the shower to act a new target. Maybe some glazed ceramics objects like a heavy flower pot would do. The glaze makes sure you can easily clean it with the shower spray. Place the new target at the edge of the pee pad.